# PHP Image upload file name

Tags: php, javascript, html

Okay, so short and sweet; I already have an image uploader working perfectly in PHP, from a HTML form. I now need to somehow store an uploaded images name to a variable in Javascript. The image name must be saved without the image path. For example: images123.jpg.

I am creating a kind of sign up form, so I don't need to save every image as a variable, just the current one, so it is saved on the users account as a variable.

Honestly, I'm completely new to PHP, and I'm still learning, so I have no clue on how to do this.

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic/172760#172760

Comment: Thanks @Natrium. As my post states, I am new to PHP, and how no clue how to do it.

Comment: use http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @Nileshpatel - I am using one very similar. Although, it does not save the image name to a JavaScript variable?

Answer (score 1):

this is work for you use your php code here

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
 $imageName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
  <input type="hidden" id="imgName" value="<?php echo $imageName; ?>" />
```

Get image name in javascript by hidden field name

```
  var imgName = document.getElementById("imgName").value;
```

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, but I forgot to mention an important point! I am learning from a text book, and the assessment is asking me to keep my PHP and Javascript all external from my HTML document.

Comment: @JadeMulholland -- So keep the PHP in a file like `processing.php` and have have the upload form in `upload.html` with a script tag to load an external `scripts.js`.

Comment: @stealthyninja - I currently have an index.html with my upload form. The forms action calls uploader.php. This saves the image to a folder called uploads. I'm not to sure on how to bring the Javascript into it, and save the image name to a variable within my external script?

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery

```
$('#upload_document_name').bind('change', function() {

        var logoName = $('#upload_document_name').val();
        $('#uploadDocumentName').attr('value', logoName);                   
});
```

**Note:** There should be hidden or text field called "uploadDocumentName".

Comment: Jquery is completely out of the quesition since I have not yet learnt it.

Comment: in the javascript page or the section ..
add this code.. 
Also include
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
Thats it!

Comment: That completely defeats the purpose of me learning how to do this activity with the instructions given to me then?

Comment: http://jquery.com/ 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp
Go through these page. I guess wont take you long. So you can learn Jquery and use it. Its Better than using Js

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. But I would prefer to learn the Javascript basics before I move on to jQuery.

Comment: jquery IS javascript. there's nothing you can't do in regular javascript that you can do in query.. it's just a library to save you some time.